# How to retrieve WETH sent from Trust Wallet to binance.us wallet

Tags: token, trustwallet

Need guidance on retrieving Wrapped Etherium sent to Binance.us wallet from Trust wallet. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Binance Bridge, customer support, not API key yet. I can see the token in my wallet via etherscan.
Also see it in meta mask.